# KineticJS / Javascript dynamic creation and immediate dragging

Tags: javascript, html, events, logic, kineticjs

What I want do is dynamically create a shape on mousedown, and then immediately have it (the shape) follow the mouse cursor until mouseup sets it in place. 
Here is what I have so far and it's not working for me.

```
addNegativeButton.on('mousedown', function(){
     var userPos = stage.getUserPosition();
     shapesLayer.add(new Kinetic.Image({
          image: imageObj,
          x: userPos.x,
          y: userPos.y,
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          rotation: 1,                      
          draggable: true,
          offset: 12
}));

var last = shapesLayer.getChildren()[shapesLayer.getChildren().length -1];
stage.on("mouseup", function(){
    last.setAbsolutePosition(stage.getUserPosition());  
    stage.off("mouseup");
});
```

To reiterate:
What I have is an 'addNegativeButton' which when clicked creates a shape.
But I want it to follow the mouse cursor until the click is released.

http://jsfiddle.net/CPrEe/37/
Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a sample jsfiddle with what you have so far and I might have a go at it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CPrEe/37/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out its rather simple ;)
After you add the element/shape, all you have to do is use the simulate function to simulate mouse down and it drags....

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});
//What I really want here is to start dragging the circle until the 
//user releases the mouse, which would then place the circle.
rect.on('mousedown', function(evt) {

    var userPos = stage.getUserPosition();
    var latestElement = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: userPos.x,
        y: userPos.y,
        radius: 20,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
    })

    layer.add(latestElement);

    // Here's the bit you want.  After adding the circle (with draggable:true) simulate the mousedown event on it which will initiate the drag
    latestElement.simulate('mousedown');

    layer.draw();
});

layer.add(rect);

stage.add(layer);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CPrEe/38/
http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#simulate

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I needed. I was reading up on simulate just recently, but wasn't sure how to use it.